# ¿Cómo iterar correctamente una columna de pandas usando un rango de valores en Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, depuración, iteradores

Sucede que tengo la siguiente información almacenada en una variable llamada `df_trading_pair`

```
           Start Date  Open Price  High Price   Low Price  Close Price         Volume                End Date
0 2022-08-08 07:15:00  0.00001241  0.00001242  0.00001238   0.00001239  16808259334.0 2022-08-08 07:19:59.999
1 2022-08-08 07:20:00  0.00001238  0.00001239  0.00001235   0.00001238   7237826684.0 2022-08-08 07:24:59.999
2 2022-08-08 07:25:00  0.00001238  0.00001239  0.00001237   0.00001238   1768234135.0 2022-08-08 07:29:59.999
3 2022-08-08 07:30:00  0.00001238  0.00001239  0.00001236   0.00001236   5243964161.0 2022-08-08 07:34:59.999
4 2022-08-08 07:35:00  0.00001236  0.00001237  0.00001235   0.00001235   8802029320.0 2022-08-08 07:39:59.999
5 2022-08-08 07:40:00  0.00001234  0.00001236  0.00001233   0.00001234   3038529151.0 2022-08-08 07:44:59.999
6 2022-08-08 07:45:00  0.00001233  0.00001236  0.00001232   0.00001235   7700037899.0 2022-08-08 07:49:59.999
7 2022-08-08 07:50:00  0.00001235  0.00001237  0.00001235   0.00001237   1929229917.0 2022-08-08 07:54:59.999
```

Estoy interesado en iterar sobre la columna `Open Price` usando un rango de 4 valores, de tal forma que imprima la siguiente información en cada iteración:

#### Iteración 1

```
0    0.00001241
1    0.00001238
2    0.00001238
3    0.00001238
Name: Open Price, dtype: float64
```

#### Iteración 2

```
1    0.00001238
2    0.00001238
3    0.00001238
4    0.00001236
Name: Open Price, dtype: float64
```

.
.
.

#### Iteración 5

```
4    0.00001236
5    0.00001234
6    0.00001233
7    0.00001235
Name: Open Price, dtype: float64
```

Como tal, ya tengo parte de la solución y es la siguiente:

```
for i in range(0, len(df_trading_pair)):
    slc = df_trading_pair["Open Price"].iloc[i : i + 4]
    print(slc)
    i = i + 1
    print("")
```

**Sin embargo**, hay un problema y es que mi solución ***itera 3 veces demás***, imprimiendo lo siguiente después de la 5 iteración:

#### Iteración 6

```
5    0.00001234
6    0.00001233
7    0.00001235
Name: Open Price, dtype: float64
```

#### Iteración 7

```
6    0.00001233
7    0.00001235
Name: Open Price, dtype: float64
```

#### Iteración 8

```
7    0.00001235
Name: Open Price, dtype: float64
```

Me gustaría saber ¿cómo puedo corregirlo?, y sí es posible, una explicación de ¿por qué mi solución no funcionó como esperaba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Si imprimes `len(df_trading_pair)` vas a ver que devuelve 8, ya que tu `dataframe` tiene 8 filas y por eso imprime 8 veces, pero tu necesitas que imprima 5 por lo que tendría que restarle 3

```
for i in range(0, len(df_trading_pair)-3):
    slc = df_trading_pair["Open Price"].iloc[i : i + 4]
    print(slc)
    i = i + 1
    print("")
```

Si piensas crear grupos de tamaño variable podrías hacer la siguiente fórmula

```
grupo = 4
limite = len(df_trading_pair)-(grupo-1)

for i in range(0, limite):
    slc = df_trading_pair["Open Price"].iloc[i : i + grupo]
    print(slc)
    i = i + 1
    print("")
```

Y de esa forma si imprimes por ejemplo en grupos de 3, imprimirá 6 grupos de 3.

Ejemplo con grupos de 3 elementos devuelve:

```
0    0.000012
1    0.000012
2    0.000012
Name: Open Price, dtype: float64

1    0.000012
2    0.000012
3    0.000012
Name: Open Price, dtype: float64

2    0.000012
3    0.000012
4    0.000012
Name: Open Price, dtype: float64

3    0.000012
4    0.000012
5    0.000012
Name: Open Price, dtype: float64

4    0.000012
5    0.000012
6    0.000012
Name: Open Price, dtype: float64

5    0.000012
6    0.000012
7    0.000012
Name: Open Price, dtype: float64
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por la explicación y la alternativa mejorada! Mi duda está resuelta.

Comment: No hay de que. Saludos!